# Regex to reject specific email

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex to match emails such that it rejects two email addresses `test@testdomain.com` and `tes2@testdomain.com` and match all other email addresses from a specific domain. So far, I have made the following pattern:

```
^(?!test@testdomain.com|tes2@testdomain.com)|(A-Z0-9)[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@testdomain.com$
```

So far, it is able to reject the main email addresses I want to block, but it accepts all other strings through this. As an alternative, I wrote the following regex:

```
^(?!test|tes2)[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@testdomain.com$
```

However, this rejects all patterns that start with either test or tes2 exclusively.

What is a better regular expression to get this scenario achieved?

Comment: `but it accepts all other strings through this` ... for which other cases is your first regex failing/unsatisfactory?

Comment: What I meant was that it pick up all strings except the rejected ones, which defeats the entire purpose of the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fixing" your regex, you need to make sure you also test for `@` inside the lookahead patterns to match `test` and `tes2` as full user names:

```
^(?!test@|tes2@)[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@testdomain\.com$
        ^     ^
```

Remember to escape a dot, too. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PHryQP/1).

However, you might want to be less restrictive on the user name part, and just use `\S+` instead of your character class:

```
^(?!test@|tes2@)\S+@testdomain\.com$
                ^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PHryQP/2). The `\S+` pattern matches any 1 or more chars other than whitespace characters.